# Handle unread or untapped notifications in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My Flutter app receives notifications well. I need however a solution for the following two problems:

Problem 1: My app is in background, I receive a notification, the user brings the app to foreground **without tapping on the notification**. I want the app to handle the untapped notification. The data from the notification needs to be read and the notification needs to disappear.

Problem 2: Very similarly, but this time the app is closed. Again the user opens the app without tapping on the notification. I want the app to handle the untapped notification. The data from the notification needs to be read and the notification needs to disappear.

How should I  best fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a solution ? @Merijn Mestdagh